# XML parsing using perl

Tags: perl

I tried to research on simple question I have but couldn't do it. I am trying to get data from web which is in XML and parse it using perl. Now, I know how to loop on repeating elements. But, I am stuck when its not repeating (I know this might be silly). If the elements are repeating, I put it in array and get the data. But, when there is only a single element it throws and error saying 'Not an array reference'. I want my code such that it can parse at both time (for single and multiple elements). The code I am using is as follows:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

open (FH, ">:utf8","xmlparsed1.txt");

my $db1 = "pubmed";
my $query  = "13054692";
my $q = 16354118;          #for multiple MeSH terms
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

$urlxml = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=$db1&id=$query&retmode=xml&rettype=abstract";
$dataxml = get($urlxml);
$data = $xml->XMLin("$dataxml");
#print FH Dumper($data);
foreach $e(@{$data->{PubmedArticle}->{MedlineCitation}->{MeshHeadingList}->{MeshHeading}})
     {
       print FH $e->{DescriptorName}{content}, ' $$ ';
     }
```

Also, can I do something such that the separator $$ will not get printed after the last element?
I also tried the following code:

```
$mesh = $data->{PubmedArticle}->{MedlineCitation}->{MeshHeadingList}->{MeshHeading};
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%$mesh)){
    print FH "$value";
}
```

But, this prints all the childnodes and I just want the content node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl's [`XML::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple) will take a single item and return it as a scalar, and if the value repeats it sends it back as an array reference.  So, to make your code work, you just have to force `MeshHeading` to always return an array reference:

```
$data = $xml->XMLin("$dataxml", ForceArray => [qw( MeshHeading )]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the part of "perldoc XML::Simple" that talks about the ForceArray option:

```
check out ForceArray because you'll almost certainly want to turn it on
```

Then you will always get an array, even if the array contains only one element.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the ForceArray option will solve this particular problem.  However you'll undoubtedly strike another problem soon after due to XML::Simple's assumptions not matching yours.  As the author of XML::Simple, I strongly recommend you read [Stepping up from XML::Simple to XML::LibXML](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=490846) - if nothing else it will teach you more about XML::Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$data->{PubmedArticle}-> ... ->{MeshHeading}` can be either a string or an array reference depending on how many `<MeshHeading>` tags are present in the document, you need to examine the value's type with `ref` and conditionally dereference it.  Since I am unaware of any terse Perl idioms for doing this, your best bet is to write a function:

```
sub toArray {
 my $meshes = shift;
 if (!defined $meshes) { return () }
 elsif (ref $meshes eq 'ARRAY') { return @$meshes }
 else { return ($meshes) }
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
foreach my $e (toArray($data->{PubmedArticle}->{MedlineCitation}->{MeshHeadingList}->{MeshHeading})) { ... }
```

To prevent `' $$ '` from being printed after the last element, instead of looping over the list, concatenate all the elements together with `join`:

```
print FH join ' $$ ', map { $_->{DescriptionName}{content} }
 toArray($data->{PubmedArticle}->{MedlineCitation}->{MeshHeadingList}->{MeshHeading});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a place where XML::Simple is being...simple.  It deduces whether there's an array or not by whether something occurs more than once.  Read the [doc](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple) and look for the ForceArray option to address this.

To only include the `' $$ '` between elements, replace your loop with

```
print FH join ' $$ ', map $_->{DescriptorName}{content}, @{$data->{PubmedArticle}->{MedlineCitation}->{MeshHeadingList}->{MeshHeading}};
```